# How can i get UPDATE statement to execute twice on the same row in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update a table in SQL. Specifically trying to update a numeric field by subtracting a numeric value in another table that I am linking by a primary key. For example update this table:

```
ID  NAME    BALANCE     CURRSTATUS
1   FRED    45          OWED
2   JAMES   21          OWED
3   JOHN    0           PAID
4   BETH    33          OWED
5   HARRY   5           REFUND
6   WILLIAM 555         COLLECT
```

By applying the rows of this table:

```
ID  AMOUNT
6   500.00
6   55.00
```

so my expected result would the the same as the first table except the balance for William would be 0 (555-500-55 = 0).

I am using a sql statement like this:

```
UPDATE 
    TABLE1
SET 
    BALANCE = BALANCE - TABLE2.AMOUNT
FROM 
    TABLE2 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE1 ON TABLE1.ID = TABLE2.ID
```

This works for the first line but does not execute the 2nd line in table2.  My end result is always 55, instead of 0. FWIW I only have this problem when the two lines in the second table are for the same person. Example: if I had a line for William and a line for John, they would both behave as expected.

Am I missing something? or is it just how UPDATE works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre-aggregate:

```
UPDATE t1
    SET BALANCE = t1.BALANCE - t2.sum_amount
FROM Table1 t1 JOIN
     (SELECT ID, SUM(Amount) as sum_amount
      FROM TABLE2
      GROUP BY ID
     ) t2
     ON t2.ID = t1.ID ;
```

Comment: i think your subquery is missing an ID to join off of but basically it works. thanks!

Comment: Just saw the same and correted this. The answer is good anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here you can go with CTE for your case.

In the CTE prepare your set like Id wise Total amounts after deducting from Balance amount. And then do update on the first table.

```
  ;WITH CTE AS(
 SELECT T1.ID , T1.BALANCE- SUM(T2.AMOUNT)  as AMT
  FROM TABLE1 T1
  INNER JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.ID = T2.ID
  GROUP BY T1.ID
  )
  UPDATE TABLE1 SET TABLE1.BALANCE  = CTE.AMT
  FROM CTE WHERE TABLE1.ID= CTE.ID
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.